# Number riddles in Spanish

Tags: traducción

I want to create some number riddles in Spanish in a form like this:

I am one more than twelve. What am I?

or

I am three less than ten. What am I?

Is this the right way to do it:

Soy uno más que doce. ¿Qué soy?

Soy tres menos que diez. ¿Qué soy?

Comment: It seems that is OK to me.

Comment: Está bien, pero también podrías poner "¿Quién soy?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translations are correct, it may be more common to say `¿Quién soy?` instead of `¿Qué soy?`, but it is more correct to say the latter phrase, since a number is a thing, and not a living being. It is obvious that a number would not speak, so it is fine to use which ever you feel more comfortable with, since using `¿Quién soy?` would give more life to the number.

`Quién` usually refers to an animal, human or non-human. It is very similar to `Who` in English.

`Qué` usually refers to an object, a thing. It is similar to `What` in English.